# How do i evaluate this limit? $\lim_{x \to 0}(\sin x - \arcsin x)/\tan^3x $

Tags: limits

$$\lim_{x \to 0}(\sin x - \arcsin x)/\tan^3x $$

I've tried l'hopital rule but it gets really messy. I've also tried splitting it into 2 limits but that doesn't work. I can't think of any meaningful substitution either.

PS: I know the answer $(-1/3)$ but I'm interested in the method.
Thank you.

Comment: Limited expansions of sine (order 3), arcsine (order 3) and tan (order 1) at zero were made for this task.

Comment: I'm a school student and we have the Taylor expansion of sinx in our syllabus but not arcsinx. So there must be a method to solve this without using those?

Comment: Then look at (sin(sin x)-x)/tan(sin x)^3 (and weep).

Comment: That still leaves tan in the mix. The only expansions I'm "allowed" to use are sinx, cosx, e^x, ln (1+x)

Comment: Say, don't you think these bits about what you know and what you don't, *ought to be in the question from the start*? Anyway, upon reflexion, I find hard to believe that the expansion of sine is in your bag of tricks but not those of tan or arcsin, especially, up to the ordrs where you need them.

Comment: I'm sorry about that,but I'm pretty sure about what's in my bag of tricks.

Comment: Did's not criticizing you but the person who allows you the Taylor expansions of $\sin$ but not $\sin^{-1}$. You could derive it yourself first before using it, since it is easy to differentiate a few times.

Comment: What @user21820 said. Plus, it is highly nonconstructive to force every problem of limit one meets to fit in the L'Hospital framework since (1) L'Hospital approach is a quite anecdotal tool, whose rôle is vastly overestimated in some (but not all) curricula, and (2) the present problem can be solved much more simply.

Comment: To wit, assuming one knows that $\sin x=x-x^3/6+o(x^3)$, one gets $$\arcsin x=x+(\arcsin x)^3/6+o((\arcsin x)^3)=x+x^3/6+o(x^3).$$ On the other hand $\sin x\sim x$ and $\cos x\to1$ hence $\tan x\sim x$ and the ratio is $$\frac{x-x^3/6-(x+x^3/6)+o(x^3)}{(x+o(x))^3}=\frac{-x^3/3+o(x^3)}{x^3+o(x^3)}= -1/3+o(1),$$ hence the result.

Comment: @Did: It is vastly overestimated in most curricula. In my university's curriculum it was taught in introductory calculus way before students possibly could (except those who already knew the stuff) understand asymptotic behaviour. See http://matheducators.stackexchange.com/a/7280/1550 and Steven's comment that he had not much choice, for another example. Observationally, we clearly see plenty of L'Hopital's rule questions on Math SE and hardly any on how to use asymptotic expansions to compute limits... =)

Comment: @user21820 Yes. And thanks for <strike>all the fish</strike> the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not so ugly if you use L'Hopital's rule strategically:

Numerator = (sin(x)-arcsin(x))*cos(x)^3

Denominator = sin(x)^3

The 3rd derivatives are respectively -2 and 6.

Comment: @raghavj: And the reason it works is that $\tan$ is always best split into $\sin$ and $\cos$. Of course, in many cases L'Hopital's rule never works (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LHospitalsRule.html; they're being kind to the rule there by saying "occasionally") so we should always use asymptotic expansions to find limits in general. Even the computer algebra systems always do that.

Comment: "strategically" Indeed it seems that, to use effectively L'H to solve nontrivial limits, one often needs some kind of never mentioned know-how, otherwise the whole thing simply does not work. Compare with the automaticity of the limited expansion approach (not to mention the respective computational simplicities of the approaches, here the OP says one needs to differentiate three times  (sin(x)-arcsin(x))*cos(x)^3... Is this even allowed by the international conventions about their human rights, to impose that maths students perform such a (mostly useless) task?)

Comment: @Did  The secret is, get yourself a copy of Mathematica, and don't grind out 3rd derivatives by hand like some starving refugee.

Comment: @JerryGuern Oh, you mean, and doing so, to abandon all hope to understand *why* the limit of the ratio is what it is? Not to mention that M is not 100% sure... Well, sorry, but no, and I will stick to *doing mathematics*, I am afraid.

Comment: @JerryGuern: I leave it as a **simple** exercise for you to find a limit which Wolfram Alpha gets wrong. It is simple if you understand limits.

Comment: @user21820  Heftier work requires Mathematica.

Comment: @JerryGuern: Of course, we should use computers to do things for us, but we still need the mathematical knowledge to **judge and verify** their outputs.